# Installation of java 1.6.31 on a sun solaris 8

Tags: java, installation, solaris, sparc

I have installed java 1.6.0.31 on a Solaris 8 Sparc but when I enter the command  :

```
Ingres > java -jar Monitor.jar c


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

at sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont (Unknown Source)

at sun.font.NativeFont.getMapper(Unknown Source)

at sun.font.NativeFont.getMapper(Unknown Source)

at sun.font.NativeFont.getMapper(Unknown Source)

at sun.font.NativeFont.getMapper(Unknown Source)

at sun.font.NativeFont.getMapper(Unknown Source)
```

What's wrong in my installation...?

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10326565

Comment: [see this steps](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/solaris_install.xml)

Comment: Yes, right but I still have sort it out....

Comment: Yeah, but you've provided little or no information for anyone else to help you.  This isn't the place to ask this question.

Comment: I have provided the information I have, if you want some other information, specific information, that I don't know could be useful, please ask and I will try to let you have it. I believed that this could be a place for asking such question, maybe because could be an error in the set of the java environment by mean of specific commands or setting into the .cshrc file of the solaris user.

Comment: What I have done is only the installation of self extracting bynary file from the root user and the setting of the PATH of the .cshrc setenv CLASSPATH .:/usr/java/jre1.6.0_31:/usr/java/jre1.6.0_31/lib:/usr/java/jre1.6.0_31/bin:$II_SYSTEM/ingres/lib/iijdbc.jar

Comment: I haven't done the part of enabling and configuration and I don't know if have to do it. Furthermore I don't have any mozilla installed in the solaris machine. Thanks

Comment: Talk to your Solaris admin.  See if they can help you.